# IPython %run magic -n switch not working

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook, ipython-magic

I'm running an IPython notebook by using the `%run` magic in another (parent) notebook.

I would like to hide some of the output in the child notebook if it is called using `%run` and think I can do this by testing for `if __name__ == '__main__'`

The IPython documentation says that, when `%run -n` switch is used:

> `__name__` is NOT set to `__main__`, but to the running file's name without extension (as python does under import).  This allows running
>   scripts and reloading the definitions in them without calling code
>   protected by an `if __name__ == "__main__"` clause.

However, it does not seem to be workign for me.  I tried this:

In `sub_notebook.ipynb`:

```
print(__name__)
```

In `parent_notebook.ipynb`:

```
%run -n sub_notebook.ipynb
```

This prints `__main__` but the documentation says that it should have printed `sub_notebook`.

Please could you let me know how I can selectively run code in `sub_notebook.ipynb` depending on whether it is being run alone or using `%run`?

I'm running IPython version 6.1.0

Comment: A quick look at the source code for `%run` shows that the function returns before even checking the `-n` switch if the filename ends with `.ipy` or `.ipynb`.  I created [an issue on the IPython project page](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/10967).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [source code to %run](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/master/IPython/core/magics/execution.py#L476) sets the `__file__` variable so we can test for this.

We can write in `sub_notebook.ipynb`:

```
try:
    __file__
    print('I am in an imported notebook')

except NameError:
    print('I am not in an imported notebook')
```

Run alone, this prints `I am not in an imported notebook`

The we can create a parent notebook `parent_notebook.ipynb` containing:

```
%run sub_notebook.ipynb
```

Running this correctly prints `I am in an imported notebook`.

We can write a simple test within `sub_notebook.ipynb`:

```
def has_parent():
    """Return True if this notebook is being run by calling
    %run in another notebook, False otherwise."""
    try:
        __file__
        # __file__ has been defined, so this notebook is 
        # being run in a parent notebook
        return True

    except NameError:
        # __file__ has not been defined, so this notebook is 
        # not being run in a parent notebook
        return False
```

Then code which should not print in the parent notebook can be protected:

```
if not has_parent():
    print('This will not print in the parent notebook')
```

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning of the child notebook `sub_notebook.ipynb`:
`run_all_examples_display_all_outputs = '__file__' not in locals()`

And again in the child notebook, whenever you have something you only want run when running the child notebook, and not run when "importing" the child notebook:
`if run_all_examples_display_all_outputs: plt.show()`